# 4 vAxes - Google Chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm plotting some data on Google Chart and I want to draw **4 variables**. Everything in working fine but my vAxes are overlaying. As I am reading on the literature, the first vAxis is on the left and the sencond on the right by default. From this on, third and fourth are also on the right!!. How can I place the thrid on the left?

```
    vAxes: {
      0: {title: 'var0', textPosition: 'in', textStyle:{color:'blue'}},
      1: {title: 'var1', textPosition: 'out', textStyle:{color:'red'}},
      2: {title: 'var2', textPosition: 'in', textStyle:{color:'orange'}},
      3: {title: 'var3', textPosition: 'out', textStyle:{color:'green'}}
    }
```

Comment: it's not possible with standard config options, all axis above zero will be on the right, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43322467/5090771) for a little help on spacing...