# Moving vAxes - Google Chart

Tags: javascript, css, charts, google-visualization

Following with my previous question ([4 vAxes - Google Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51670815/4-vaxes-google-chart)), as far as I can not move the axis itself, I found that the text of the axis has a x position. I am wondering if I can change this position. Something like this:

```
    $("[x=845]").each(function(){
      x = 800;
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, it's possible, the chart is drawn using svg,
once the chart's `'ready'` event fires,
you can work with the svg elements, similar to working with html elements

but it will be difficult to work out the exact placement of the labels,
especially if the chart is responsive in size

see following working snippet for an example,
the chart bounds are used to help with placement,
however, the chart does have a set width...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y0', 'y1', 'y2', 'y3'],
    ['A', 15, 30, 65, 100],
    ['B', 12, 32, 67, 101],
    ['C', 14, 32, 67, 101],
    ['D', 18, 33, 68, 110],
    ['E', 17, 33, 68, 110],
    ['F', 17, 45, 70, 112],
    ['G', 18, 46, 71, 113],
    ['H', 22, 47, 72, 110],
    ['I', 24, 47, 72, 112],
    ['J', 20, 47, 72, 105],
    ['K', 17, 45, 70, 105],
    ['L', 17, 33, 68, 104],
    ['M', 16, 33, 68, 105],
    ['N', 15, 32, 67, 103]
  ]);

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var chartBounds = chartLayout.getChartAreaBoundingBox();
    var labelBounds;
    var labelGap;
    var labelIndex = -1;
    var labelWidth;
    var xCoord;

    var labels = container.getElementsByTagName('text');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(labels, function(label) {
      // move axis labels
      if ((label.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'start') && (label.getAttribute('fill') === '#ff0000')) {
        labelIndex++;
        labelBounds = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('vAxis#1#label#' + labelIndex);
        labelWidth = labelBounds.width;
        labelGap = chartBounds.left - parseFloat(label.getAttribute('x'));
        xCoord = chartBounds.left + chartBounds.width + labelGap - labelWidth;
        label.setAttribute('x', xCoord);
      }

      // move axis title
      if ((label.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle') && (label.textContent === 'var1')) {
        labelBounds = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('vAxis#1#title');
        labelWidth = labelBounds.width;
        labelGap = chartBounds.left - parseFloat(label.getAttribute('x'));
        xCoord = chartBounds.left + chartBounds.width + labelGap + labelWidth;
        var rotate = 'rotate(-90 ' + xCoord + ' ' + label.getAttribute('y') + ')';
        label.setAttribute('x', xCoord);
        label.setAttribute('transform', rotate);
      }
    });
  });

  chart.draw(data, {
    chartArea: {
      right: 136
    },
    series: {
      0: {targetAxisIndex: 0},
      1: {targetAxisIndex: 1},
      2: {targetAxisIndex: 2},
      3: {targetAxisIndex: 3}
    },
    vAxes: {
      0: {title: 'var0', textPosition: 'in', textStyle:{color:'blue'}},
      1: {title: 'var1', textPosition: 'out', textStyle:{color:'red'}},
      2: {title: 'var2', textPosition: 'in', textStyle:{color:'orange'}},
      3: {title: 'var3', textPosition: 'out', textStyle:{color:'green'}}
    },
    width: 1264
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! It's going to take me some time, but with your help I will figure out :) :)