# Can we draw a bar chart with different axis for all x-axis variables using google charts or any other library?

Tags: javascript, php, charts, highcharts, google-visualization

Dual bar chart:
[image]

Can we draw a bar chart with different y-axis for Steam, LFE, FE1, FE2, and Preheat(bar chart image link above)?

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43322467/5090771)...